# vuejs fetching api request and .then() function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm fetching api request via basic `fetchSpecialityArray()` function:

```
  fetchSpecialityArray(){
    this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/speciality')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.specialityTest = result).then(this.checkSpeciality())
  },
```

then in `checkSpeciality()` method I'm checking if this request is complete:

```
  checkSpeciality(){
      console.log('check if complete and show array: ')
      console.log(this.specialityTest)
  },
```

Unfortunately I've got empty array in my console. When I trigger `fetchSpecialityArray()` method again I've got correct response in console.

What is the cause of this behaviour and how should I correct my code to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> then(this.checkSpeciality())
> ```

You are calling `this.checkSpeciality` **immediately** and then passing its return value (`undefined` because there is no return statement) to `then()`.

You need to pass a function to `then()`.

Since `this.checkSpeciality` makes use of `this` you need to capture the correct value of `this` too. You can use `bind` to create a function which will all `checkSpeciality` with the correct value of `this`.

```
.then(this.checkSpeciality.bind(this))
```

Comment: thank you, your solution works, thank you also for an explanation. I was confused, also `then(() => this.checkSpeciality())` works for me

Comment: I accepted Radonirina answer, because he was first and his solution also works, but your explanation is better. If I could I would accept both answers

Comment: my website shows he was first :) anyway. Your answer is also correct and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: This is the superior answer. It is complete with a why and how to fix. Being first is irrelevent if the answer is crap @gileneusz

Answer (score 1):

Then require a function, here you pass a function that you invoke. You should invoke the function into the callback function as you can see int the following code:

```
.then(() => this.checkSpeciality())
```

Otherwise, you can pass the function without invoking it.

```
.then(this.checkSpeciality)
```

Comment: "Try this" — Why? This is entirely free of anything resembling an explanation.

Comment: `then(this.checkSpeciality)` — Won't that decouple the function from the correct `this` value and cause it to fail?

Comment: Update the answer @Quentin. Just trying to help him! :D

Comment: guys, thank you all for help :) I was almost giving this up, because today nothing works for me :)